# Microsoft SQL Server, selecting an id and inserting into another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this code for inserting some rows into the following table - and i am getting the id from another table that is already populated. Using Compact 4.0 Local Database Here with C# and Razor.

get id from sortedWord table:

```
Id | SortedWord
0    act
```

insert data into words table:

```
Id | Word | SortedId
0    cat    0
1    tac    0

    for (var i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++){
        queryString = "SELECT Id FROM SortedWords WHERE SortedWord = @0";
        var sortedId = db.QuerySingle(queryString, sortWord(words[i]));
        queryString = "INSERT INTO Words (Word, SortedId) VALUES (@0, @1)";
        db.Query(queryString, words[i], sortedId.Id);
    }
```

Trouble is the select statement is inefficient, is it possible to do this without a select statement, something like select into: I saw some examples here but cant make sense of it.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can simply use:

```
INSERT Words (Word, SortedID)
SELECT  @0, ID
FROM    SortedWords
WHERE   SortedWord = @1;
```

Then your c# would become:

```
queryString = " INSERT Words (Word, SortedID) SELECT @0, ID FROM SortedWords WHERE SortedWord = @1;"
db.Query(queryString, words[i], sortedwords[i]);
```

Or you could just embed your first query into your second:

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO Words (Word, SortedId) VALUES (@0, (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM SortedWords WHERE SortedWord = @1))";
db.Query(queryString, words[i], sortWord(words[i]));
```

---

However, if you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, I would go one further and do all the inserts at once using a [Table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The first step would be to create the type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TwoStringList AS TABLE (Value1 VARCHAR(MAX), Value2 VARCHAR(MAX));
```

I have used a generic name so the type is more reusable. You can then create a procedure that accepts this type as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertWords @StringList dbo.TwoStringList READONLY
AS
    INSERT Words (Word, SortedID)
    SELECT  sl.Value1, sw.ID
    FROM    SortedWords sw
            INNER JOIN @StringList sl
                ON sw.SortedWord = sl.Value2;
```

Then you can pass this to an SQL command with something like this:

```
var datatable = new DataTable();
datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value1", typeof(string)));
datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value2", typeof(string)));

for (var i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
{
    var dr = datatable.NewRow();
    dr[0] = words[i];
    dr[1] = sortedwords[i];
    datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your Connection String"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertWords", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter{ 
                                            ParameterName = "@StringList", 
                                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                                            TypeName = "dbo.TwoStringList",
                                            Value = datatable
                                            });
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/491d2/5)**

Comment: Getting the Error: {"A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement."}.

Comment: at the line db.Query(queryString, words[i], sortWord(words[i])); when the query attempts to be executed, the SQL seems to work actually but doesn't allow a parameter, which kind of ruins the whole point of it. If i just change the @0 to say "hey" it will work and insert a load of "hey"'s

Comment: What does `db.Query` actually call? It looks to be the way this adds parameters to the command if it works with out it. I have edited my answer to show another method where I have just embedded your first query within the second.

Comment: I found using @0 did not work however concatenating it did work, but im aware that is unsecure. Either way your query (the first one) was bang on thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with C# syntax, but you can do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO Words (Word, SortedId) 
SELECT @0,id 
FROM sortedWords 
WHERE sortedWord = @0;
```

Comment: This would also select sortedWord from SortedWords table, where as i only want to select the Id from that table, and then insert the standard word from a variable:

Comment: But you are searching WHERE sortedWord = @0, so they are the same thing, no?

Comment: so I have a variable "cat", get the id where its sorted word is "act" from the sorted words table, lets say that id is 2 - then insert cat and that id "2" into the words table.

Comment: Yes! That is what this is doing :)

Comment: At which point is "cat" being inserted? im, searching for "act" not inserting it

Comment: I changed my answer, but i'm not sure i should. If you are searching for act, when in your current code do you change @0 to cat?

Comment: @wazzaday. see if this is what you are looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30ebe/1

Comment: the variable cat is called words[i] i run it through a function which sorts it a turns into act sortWord(words[i]); then i have cat and act and the query is db.Query(queryString, words[i], sortWord(words[i]));

Comment: Then you have to put in the SELECT the variable that has 'cat' and in the WHERE the one that has 'act', but from your question, i couldn't see that.